# Unable to Join Google Group

Tags: forum, google-groups, google-groups-api

When I try to join google group, I'm getting an error **you do not have permission to join this forum**. Even, I haven't restricted my new user to join my group. Anyone know how I get permission or get around this?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appcelerator-titanium

Answer (score 1):

There are different security levels you can assigned to a Group, one of them is if the group is open for new members; this must be a security setting that you need to enable, please go through the [reference link](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33343) with information about Google Groups.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can join a Google Group to have discussions about a topic or to communicate with your team, organization, class, or other group. Some groups grant immediate membership, but others require you to request membership.please go through the [reference link](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205?hl=en) with information about Google Groups.